# Override ToString() returning System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Problem_2.Movie]

Tags: c#, tostring

so I'm having an issue with my overridden ToString() method. It keeps outputting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Problem_2.Movie] in my textbox and not the information I need.

I have the ToString() method overridden in my Movie Class.

```
 class Movie
{
    private string movieName { get; set; }
    private int number { get; set; }
    private string releaseDate { get; set; }
    private string location { get; set; }
    private string genre { get; set; }
    private int rating { get; set; }
    private int duration { get; set; }
    private double price { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> movList = new List<Movie>();


    public Movie(string movieName,int number,string releaseDate,string location, string genre, int rating, int duration, double price)
    {
        this.movieName = movieName;
        this.number = number;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.location = location;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.price = price;

    }

    public Movie()
    {
        //blank constructor
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        String movies ="";
        for(int i = 0; i < movList.Capacity; i++)
        {
            movies += movList[i].movieName + "-" + movList[i].number + "-" + movList[i].releaseDate + "-" 
                + movList[i].genre + "-" + movList[i].duration + ": $" + movList[i].price + "\n";
        }

        return movies;

    }
```

and I'm calling it on a button click, which then should be displaying the information in a textbox.

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = mov.movList.ToString();        
    }
```

Comment: Try use this `textBox1.Text = mov.ToString();`

Comment: You are calling the ToString method of the List<Movie> not the ToString method of the Movie class

Comment: Side note: do not use string concatenations. Use a `StringBuilder` instead

Comment: Also, please use normal c# conventions: properties go in PascalCase, and remove all those `this.`

Comment: Also, it is very uncommon to have a List<Movie> as a property of a Movie. I would say that in your context is plain wrong

Comment: So, I've tried textBox1.text = mov.ToString() but the textBox remains blank; nothing is being shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overridden the `ToString` method of class `Movie`. So you have to call it on the instance of `Movie` and not on the public field `movList`.

```
textBox1.Text = mov.ToString();
```

*Notes on the implementation of `ToString` method*:

You should replace the `Capacity` property with the `Count` property:

```
for(int i = 0; i < movList.Count; i++)
```

The `Capacity` property according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets or sets the total number of elements the internal data structure
>   can hold without resizing.

Whereas the `Count` property ([List.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx))

> Gets the number of elements contained in the list

which is that you want.

You should avoid using string concatenation, when you have to concatenate many strings. In the latter case you should prefer to create an instance of the `StringBuilder` class and append the string you want to concatenate. Last you by calling the `ToString` on the `StringBuilder` instance you have created, you will get the concatenation of the strings you wanted to concatenate.

*Notes regarding the Movie class design* (as they have already pointed out by commentators of your question)

- Try to make use of common C# naming conventions ([Names of Type Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members))
- You expose a public field named movList, which is a list of `Movie` class objects and this field is defined on the `Movie` class level. This choice is a bit confusing. If this class would have represented a MovieStore then it would be quite reasonable to have a list with the Movies in the MovieStore. What a list of Movies represent on a instance of a Movie?
- Last but not least, it's a bit weird to have class that represents Movie and we can't read it's release date or duration etc. The properties you have defined are all private !

Another design it could be the following. Apparently there are missing a lot of things here, since I created it based on *assumptions* I did by reading your class.

```
// Define an enum for Genre and populate with as many Genres you want.
enum Genre { Action, Adventure, Animation, Biography, Comedy, Crime }

// Define an enum for Rating and populate it accordingly
enum Rating { GeneralAudiences, ParentalGuidanceSuggested, ParentsStronglyCautioned, Restricted, AdultsOnly }

class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; }
    public string Location { get; }
    public Genre Genre { get; }
    public Rating Rating { get; }
    // Prefer decimal for money. It's more accurate than double.
    public decimal Price { get; }

    public Movie(int id, string name, DateTime releaseDate, string location, Genre genre, Rating rating, Decimal price)
    {
        Id = id;
        // It's meaningless we talk about for a Movie without a name. 
        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        ReleaseDate = releaseDate;
        Location = location;
        Genre = genre;
        Rating = rating;
        Price = price;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id: {Id}, Name: {Name}, ReleaseDate: {ReleaseDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}, Location: {Location}, Genre: {Genre}, Rating: {Rating}";
    }
}
```

You could spot here a few things about the above class.

- We replaced the Genre and Rating properties with enums. Doing so we will make our code more readable an we will *instruct* the users of our class on how to create a movie. Think about someone pass action, other Acction, another one ACTION etc...as the Genre of the movie. This was feasible with our initial design. Now it can pick only one value from our enum, for instance `Genre.Action`.
- By asking for a release date in the form of a string is not the best way. Someone quite probably would make a mistake. Think about the case where we have two callers and none of them makes a mistake while typing but they use a different format, "dd/MM/yyyy" and "MM/dd/yyyy" ! How would you compare two movies then based on their release date. By imposing release date to be a `DateTime`, you avoid all these *bad* cases.
- We replaced `double` with `decimal`, since it is more accurate.
- We removed the default constructor. Doing so, we show the one way to the users of our class to create a valid movie object. If we had included also the default constructor, one could be able to create a movie like `var movie = new Movie { Location = "uknown"}`, a movide without name, release date etc. !

Comment: Trying to change movList.Capacity to movList.Length gives an error "no definition for 'Length' " and using mov.ToString() on button_click has the textBox1 remain blank.

Comment: @DGMX My bad...just corrected it :( Count it the correct.

Comment: Now it's only missing a complete redefinition of the movie class and it would be the perfect answer

Comment: So, I've changed the textBox1 to equal mov.ToString(), however now when the button is clicked, nothing is displayed in the textBox1

Comment: @DGMX This is reasonable, because on creating a movie object you just create an empty list of movies attached to this object, `public List<Movie> movList = new List<Movie>();`. If you don't add to this list movies, it would remain empty.